# Recognizing VC++ compiler in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, compilation, mex

In order to install MatConvNet, it is needed to use a C++ compiler. Since MingW-w64 C++ does not work, Visual C++ complier should be used. However, I faced some problems with that. 
Although both of them are installed, I could not use them. 
Using Mingw compiler, the installation process will be failed and VC++ could not be recognized. I installed Visual Studio 2017, but when the following command issued, it seems that it is not recognizable.

```
>> mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C++','Selected')
```

**Output**:

```
ans = 

         CompilerConfiguration with properties:

         Name: 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'
 Manufacturer: 'GNU'
     Language: 'C++'
      Version: '4.x'
     Location: '$MINGWROOT'
    ShortName: 'mingw64-g++'
     Priority: 'E'
      Details: [1×1 mex.CompilerConfigurationDetails]
   LinkerName: '$MINGWROOT\bin\g++'
LinkerVersion: ''
       MexOpt: some path
```

So, the question is how to make the MATLAB to recognize VC++ as the primary compiler?

P.s. Both compilers are resided in MATLAB's mexopts directory.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `mex -setup` as described in the documentation? It should allow you to select a compiler. Also, which version of MATLAB do you use? Each version recognizes only a limited set of MSVC versions. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/choose-c-or-c-compilers.html

Comment: Using the mex -setup command the following error will be raised  
'' Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. You can install the freely available MinGW-w64 C/C++ compiler; see Install
MinGW-w64 Compiler. For more options, visit http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2017a/.''
However, using the setenv() for MingW everything is OK. The problem is how to do so for VC++.

Comment: Did you install the compiler? Last time I installed, the default installation set of Visual Studio did not contain the C / C++ compiler.

Comment: Make sure you check what @Daniel mentioned. MVS does not install C++ compiler by default! So unless you explicitly selected it during installation, you may not have MVS installed. And no, compilers are not resident in `mexopts` directory, that is purely `xml` files with compiler options

Comment: @Daniel, I installed the compiler but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The [documented way](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/choose-c-or-c-compilers.html) of selecting a C++ compiler is to use `mex -setup c++`. However, if this does not work for some reason (as appears to be the case for OP), then one can configure the compiler manually:

In the output of `mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C++','Selected')`, there is a `MexOpt` value. This points to the file that contains the information about the selected compiler that `mex` will use.

You can take any of the XML files in the `mexopts` directory (which can be found here: `$MATLABROOT/bin/<arch>/mexopts`) and copy and rename it to match the value of `mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C++').MexOpt`.

Depending on your platform (I have not seen what this looks like under Windows) you might have to edit in some paths to your compiler and related directories.

It is recommended to have your configured C and C++ compilers match.

Comment: The renaming trick worked but I still get the previous error:
'"No supported compiler or SDK was found."
Further, mex - setup command does not work anymore and it produces the aforementioned error.

Comment: @dtr43: Ah, that explains it. Could you post that as an answer? It might help someone else running into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your priceless help and advice. Sure, I'll post it!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the methods provided as answers and comments didn't work. I just found this is a bug in MATLAB R2016b and R2017a.
The workaround for this problem can be found at the following link.

[mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1487958](http://mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1487958)